# Get browser URL in an outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook add-in that requires to save email location. For that, I want to get the browser URL corresponding to the opened email . How do I get the outlook host window's URL from the outlook add-in? Is there any method to save email location?
`window.location` gives me the location of my add-in not that of the browser.

Comment: Hello, you can use the graph API to get the item's link using the weblink property. Details are here in this link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the graph API to get the item's link using the weblink property. Details are here in this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0